# SWT Styled Text partial redraw

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have problem with SWT StyledText. I draw new element on StyledText's GC whenever resize or paint event take place. What's more I also force redraw of the whole StyledText in every second. 
My problem is that this redraw is sometimes visible because StyledText sometimes funny "blinks".
My question is, is it somehow possible in SWT to redraw only part of the widget, like it is possible in Swing?

Comment: Counter question: Why do you need to manually redraw it every second?

Comment: Because I want to show something what is blinking (every second) on this styled text in position that depends of the line which is currently being edited

Comment: I hope you are going to follow the accessibility rules for blinking text which state that it must be possible to turn this off (see for example http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)

Comment: I do follow this convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `redraw(x, y, width, height, false)` on the `StyledText` control to ask for just a part of the control to be redrawn.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I'm blind. Anyway, that was what I was looking for, thanks.